# php ZipArchive() utf8 encoding problems with filenames

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters

I use ZipArchive(); to list the file names inside a Zip archive (uploaded on FTP, not created by server).

Problem is that the file names contain french caracters (accents like é à ô â à è) that are not displayed proprely. Instead i get a "�" symbol.

The page is encoded in utf8 and the rest of the script doesnt have any problem with accents

i tried running htmlentities() or utf8_encode() on $toune but it didnt help...

here's my code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$downloadlink = "pp/86 Crew - 2000 - Bad Bad Reggae.zip";
            $za = new ZipArchive();
            $za->open($downloadlink);
            for( $i = 0; $i < $za->numFiles; $i++ ){
                $stat = $za->statIndex( $i );
                $tounes = array( basename( $stat['name'] ) . PHP_EOL );
                foreach($tounes as $toune) {
                echo $toune;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Use [`iconv`](http://php.net/iconv) or [`mb_string`](http://php.net/mb-string). Encode them to utf-8, if needed.

Comment: i'm confused... example please ?

Comment: `$tounes = array( basename( iconv('YourCharSetName', 'UTF-8', $stat['name']) ) . PHP_EOL );`

Comment: "YourCharSetName" is supposed to be the charset of the zip's filenames ? but how can i know what is the characters encoding of the filenames inside the ZIP archive ?

Comment: Well, it is french, as you mentioned. Which used for it im most of the times?

Comment: Only some of them are in french... Other are in english... The zip files are uploaded by my users so i suppose they have a lot of different charset/encodings

Comment: `preg_match('/[éàôâàè]/')` might help to detect french ones. I used something same for cyrillic once.

Comment: The translate function`iconv` is _not_ what you're looking for. It will change the filenam (€ becomes EUR) . Use `mb_convert_encoding()` for this kind of conversations.